# select drop down in IE 9 using java selenium RC

Tags: java, selenium-rc

I am new to  java and i am trying to automate a feature.

I am facing an issue and that is related to IE 9 , selenium RC and Java code.

Problem - 
My code is not clicking on the drop down, tried the following two commends

1. selenium.click("class=");
2. selenium.click("id=");

Now my concern is either of these commands are not working for me.
I have to select a value from the drop down. I have also tried to directly opening the drop down value but it didn't work.

Can some one tell me why it is not happening ? Am I using a wrong approach ?

Thanks,
Dushyant

Answer (score 0):

Try using selenium.select("id", "value") instead of selenium.click

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Reply. I will try this and let you know if any issues.